# How to run Java application on startup of Ubuntu Linux

Tags: java, linux, sockets, ubuntu, init

I have a requirement where I need to develop application that reads TCP/IP Socket. I successfully made the program as Java program with No GUI means as soon as program runs it starts listening to the Socket and gets the response with the help of Netbeans IDE. Now as per my requirement i have to start execution of this program as soon as Linux system Booted.

Actually I am very novice in Java and Linux Platform, so have few doubts..

1. Is my Socket Program with no GUI is fine to be run as per my requirement.
2. How can I write script to run jar on Linux Boot up, I got to know. `init.d` is meant for this.

Comment: `/etc/rc.local` is the lazy place to put code to run on system start.

Comment: @Paul - Nice of you to offer an alternative

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ideally you should create a service wrapper for your java application and then make this service run on startup example [here](http://www.jcgonzalez.com/linux-java-service-wrapper-example).

Use
`sudo update-rc.d mytestserv defaults` to run your service wrapper on startup on Ubuntu

Comment: What if i wont change PID_PATH_NAME=/tmp/MyService-pid in your program.If i let it be as it is.Will it be OK

Comment: one More Silly question.Am sorry sir i am very novice to Linux ..How to come out of this command sudo vi /etc/init.d/mytestserv  after pasting the script and execute next command i.e sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/mytestserv

Comment: you mean getting out the vi editor!!?? press "ESC +  :wq + "INTRO" to exit. If you mean to reboot the machine try "sudo reboot now" or "sudo reboot"

Comment: Got it sir..One More thing if my service is in started Mode and after some time i rebooted my Linux System then My Service will automatically be Started.Am i Right?

Comment: Yes Reboot you computer if you can to double check it. Lot's of luck!

Answer (score 2):

So two things you'll need to do:

First create a small shell script to start your java program from a terminal. As you have packaged as a jar have a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/run.html), specifically the `JAR Files as Applications` section.

This may be sufficient: (although you'll want to use the full path to Java)

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar path_to_jar_file
```

You should be able to run your script and successfully start your program.

Once you've got it starting from a script you can use standard linux tools to start the script. Either putting it in `/etc/rc.local`, or as you're using Ubuntu, use [update-rc.d](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/update-rc.d.8.html) to start it on boot. See [here](http://jasonleveille.com/blog/2013/01/debian-ubuntu-adding-a-startup-script/) for a very simple example of using `update-rc.d`

Hope this helps,

Will