# Automatically running a Java application at OS(windows and ubuntu) startup without user interference

Tags: java, windows, jar, ubuntu-14.04

Am i need some way of starting my Java application without forcing the user to run the application manually. i have birthday reminder jar file. Now i need to popup the window when the user have birthday it will popup a message or vice versa . Can anyone provide any assistance?

Comment: Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953525/run-java-application-at-windows-startup?rq=1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18874414/automatically-running-a-java-application-at-os-startup?rq=1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22712080/how-to-run-java-application-on-startup-of-ubuntu-linux?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu make you application as service and start it while os boot up(using chkconfig). and in Windows you can add it your application in startup(make a .bat file and put it to windows startup folder)